# Is there a nice way to narrow a type requirement?

Tags: php, inheritance, type-hinting

Given the following code as a little example (also running [here](https://3v4l.org/JiuZj)):

```php
<?php

namespace Base;

class Status {}

interface StatusHydratorInterface {
    public function hydrate($data, Status $status): Status;
}

class Doer {
    public function __construct(StatusHydratorInterface $hydrator){}
}

namespace Cricket;

class Status extends \Base\Status {
    public function doSomethingCrickety(): self { return $this; }
}

interface StatusHydratorInterface {
    public function hydrate($data, Status $status): Status;
}

class StatusHydrator implements StatusHydratorInterface {
    public function hydrate($data, Status $status): Status 
    {
        return $status->doSomethingCrickety();
    }
}

$doer = new \Base\Doer(new StatusHydrator());
```

It understandable errors with `Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Base\Doer::__construct(): Argument #1 ($hydrator) must be of type Base\StatusHydratorInterface, Cricket\StatusHydrator given`

If I make the `Cricket` interface extend the `Base` one, it errors with a similar `Fatal error: Declaration of Cricket\StatusHydratorInterface::hydrate($data, Cricket\Status $status): Cricket\Status must be compatible with Base\StatusHydratorInterface::hydrate($data, Base\Status $status): Base\Status`

The only solution I can think is completely remove the `Cricket` interface, have the class extend the `Base` one, and do an `instanceof` check in the implementation, but that goes against the point of having typehints IMO.

Do I have any other solutions on nicely being able to type hint this? Or just wait and pray for PHP generics ?